# AngularJS: Call a function when system date changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I want to refresh the content of my page when user's system date is changed.
The user visits the page at 03-11-2012 (3rd Nov) at mid night, and when the system date is changed to 04-11-2014 (4th Nov) the content should be refreshed or a function should be called.

we can use `$interval(checksysDate(),5000)` where `checksysDate()` will check if the date is changed at the interval of `5000`. But, I was wondering if we can use `$scope.$watch` on system date (only date i.e 3rd or 4th Nov and not time).
 Any elegant solutions ??

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14236033/1182982 might be useful

Comment: Great comment of Yasser. If you understand the digest-cycle, you will understand why your idea won't work. 

But why you just dont implement a timeout where you set the remaining time to 24 - current Time? Still better than an interval...

Comment: Agree with @Charminbear. Better not to use $watch. Calculate time gap when you open the page. And setTimeout(Next day  - now ) to change date(And then use interval to trigger date change per 24 hours).

Comment: thanks @Charminbear! I'll try the solution you suggested. and thanks Tyler for the flow.

Comment: The interval won't work, because well.. the page will reload. But the timeout until the next day starting when the page loads is a valid idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, but it ain't pretty...

```js
angular.module("test", []).controller("TimeCtrl", function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
  $scope.nowSeconds = $scope.seconds; //this one is just for presentation

  $interval(function() {
    this.seconds = new Date().getSeconds(); //you can put here day
  }.bind($scope), 5000);

  $scope.$watch('seconds', function(oldV, newV) {
    if(oldV !== newV)
        $scope.nowSeconds = newV; //you can put your reaction here - reload page
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="TimeCtrl">
  {{nowSeconds}}
</div>
```